# How to show name of user who wrote comment (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs

In my rails app I have users(authors),posts(articles),comments. If registered user write comment to article, I want to show his name beside his comment, if  he isn't registered user  I want to show "Anonymous" beside his comment. How can I do this?

comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :post_id, :text
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
end
```

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

validates :fullname,      :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :password,      :presence => true
validates :email,         :presence => true, :uniqueness => true


devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :fullname


end
```

post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :text, :title, :tag_list
acts_as_taggable

validates :user_id, :presence => true
validates :title,   :presence => true
validates :text, :presence => true

belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
end
```

view file (show.html.erb)

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>

 <p>
 Created: <%= @post.created_at.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")%> by
 <%=  link_to @post.user.fullname, user_posts_path(@post.user) %>
 </p>


<p><%=simple_format @post.text %></p>
<p>
Tags: <%= raw @post.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>


<p><%= comment.created_at.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") %>
by <%= HERE I NEED ADD SOMETHING%></p>
<p><%= comment.text %></p>
<p><%= link_to "Delete comment", [@post, comment], :method => :delete, 
:confirm =>"Are   you   sure?"%></p>
<% end %>

<%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build] do |f| %>
<p><%= f.text_area :text %></p>
<p><%= f.submit "Post comment" %></p>
<% end %>


<% if user_signed_in?%>
<p>
<%= link_to "Back", posts_path %>

<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post) %>
<%= link_to "Delete", @post, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?"%>
 </p>
<% end%>
```

Comment: Please post the view file so that we know where you want to show and suggest some feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by calling the `user` method on the comment, and then `name` on that:

```
<%= comment.user.name %>
```

You can also define a `to_s` method in the `User` model:

```
def to_s
  name
end
```

Which would mean you could get away with doing just this in the view:

```
<%= comment.user %>
```

If you're loading a whole bunch of comments, then I would recommend loading them this way:

```
@comments = Comment.includes(:user)
```

If you don't have that `includes(:user)` there, then Rails will issue a new query for every single comment to find that comment's user. Doing it this way makes Rails load all the users for all the comments upfront in just one query.

Comment: I did what you say but name of user beside comment is still empty

Comment: Then you did not associate any user with that comment.

Comment: When you create the comment in the `CommentsController`, `Comment.new(:user => current_user)`

Comment: what about Anonymous, if he leave a comment how to show above his message 'by Anonymous'?

Comment: Then create a new User object to represent Anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create two assocations pointing to the same table:

```
class CreatePostss < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.text :text
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :author, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Here user_id references the target user of the post and author_id references the user writing the post. Both reference users.id.

Then create two belongs_to associations in your post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :author, 
    class_name: 'User', 
    inverse_of: :authored_posts
end
```

And two has_many associations in your User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # posts about this user
  has_many :posts 
  # postss written by this user 
  has_many :authored_posts, 
    class_name: 'Post',
    foreign_key: :author_id,
    inverse_of: :author
end
```

Here is the controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:new, :create]
  
  # ...

  def new
    @post = @user.posts.new
  end

  def create
    @post = @user.posts.new(post_params) do |c|
      c.author = current_user
    end
    if @post.save
      redirect_to doctor_path(id: @user.id)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end 

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # ...
end
```

To display posts you would do:

```
<% @user.posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="post">
  <div class="body">
    <%= post.body %>
  </div>
  <p class="author"><%= post.author.email %></p>
</div>  
<% end %>
```